# Disable Sharing Wizard with Batch?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch

How can I disable the Sharing Wizard option that's win the Folders Options? I want to be able to disable it with a batch command. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the Sharing Wizard option:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" ^
     /T REG_DWORD /V SharingWizardOn /D 0
```

To enable the Sharing Wizard option:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" ^
     /T REG_DWORD /V SharingWizardOn /D 1
```

Use `/F` switch to suppress `Value SharingWizardOn exists, overwrite(Yes/No)?` prompt and force writing without prompting.

**Note** `^` and new line used merely for better readability, apply an one-liner, e.g. to enable the Sharing Wizard option:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /T REG_DWORD /V SharingWizardOn /D 1
```